# xrandr very slow when changing from laptop to monitor

Tags: xrandr

I am using archlinux and i3-wm. I have a laptop connected with an external monitor via HDMI. I use the following commands to toggle the screens:

From laptop to monitor (it takes 4.0sec):

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --output LVDS1 --off
```

From monitor to laptop (it takes less than 0.5sec):

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900 --output HDMI1 --off
```

From monitor to laptop the change is almost instantaneous, but from the laptop to monitor it takes almost 10 times more time.

This is the xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1600x900      60.00*+
   1368x768      60.00
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00
   960x540       60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00
   800x450       60.00
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       60.00
   640x360       60.00
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1680x1050     59.88
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      74.98    59.90
   1280x960      60.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94
   720x400       70.08
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is hardware. Generally speaking, in my experience, the built-in screens on laptops tend to connect faster than external monitors. Effectively, your HDMI connection has to "wake up" everything down the line, especially if your laptop has a discrete GPU that goes into any sort of power-saving/sleep mode when not in use.

Bear in mind that you aren't "switching screens" per se, you are entirely turning one output off and enabling the output to the other. As far as the monitor is concerned, your laptop isn't even really connected until you enable it.